# UITableViewControllerを使ってsegueする時にindexPathForSelectedRowが参照できない

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift4

UITableViewControllerを使ってcellが選択された時にPlayBackViewController(UIViewController)へsegueしたいのですがprepare(for segue:で
let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
とすると以下のエラーが出ます。（添付コードの下から5行目）
Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)
だれかお知恵をお貸しください。

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableVIew: UITableView!

    let voiceTextArray = ["11111","222222","333333","444444","55555"]
    let dateTimeArray = ["dateTime1","dateTime2","dateTime3","dateTime4","dateTime5"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableVIew.delegate = self
        tableVIew.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return voiceTextArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableVIew.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "protoCell")as! ProtoTableViewCell
        cell.voiceTextLable.text = voiceTextArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.dateTimeLabel.text = dateTimeArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowPlayBackView" {
            let detailViewController = segue.destination as! PlayBackViewController

            //  ERROR :Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'
            let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            detailViewController.voiceText = voiceTextArray[myIndexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableVIew: UITableView!
```

は

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

ですね。
tableViewのiが大文字になっています。

参考元：
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164244/ambiguous-reference-to-member-tableview-numberofrowsinsection-why-this-err

■追記
この場合、

```
let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

を

```
let myIndexPath = self.tableVIew.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

にした方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: 夏バテかな。とにかく、ありがとうございました。直りました。